# Modelagem para permissões de usuarios

Tags: modelagem, design-pattern, modelo-relacional

Eu acho que esta pergunta é mais de analise de modelagem na verdade não sei se enquadra no padrão de perguntas discutido pelo **meta.pt.stackoverflow.com**. Preciso fazer meu sistema de um jeito que quase tudo terá permissões de usuário, fiz a seguinte modelagem das entidades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem talvez eu tenha que colocar permissões de "ACESSO e CRUD" para fabricante do produto ou permissões para o usuário que não tem a ver com a categoria ou fabricante, por exemplo: permissões para usuário cadastrar outros usuários e dar permissões para eles, o problema é que no meu estilo atual de modelagem eu teria que criar outra tabela de permissões para o fabricante e outra tabela de permissões para cadastro de outros usuários, eu gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão de modelagem(Designer Patterns) pra esse tipo de situação?

> Diagrama: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bfx1O0eapYR2xHLXFMQkR2N2s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Não é um desgin pattern, mas o que está faltando aí é uma tabela `Perfil`. Um usuário tem um ou mais perfis, e as permissões de acesso estão ligadas ao perfil. Dentre essas permissões, algumas se relacionam com `Categorias` (quem sabe uma tabela `PermissaoCategoria` contendo o id da permissao e o id da categoria).

Comment: Veja que nessa nova modelagem não tem problema nenhuma uma permissão não ser relacionada à nenhuma categoria (e, de quebra é possível atribuir uma permissão para várias categorias e vice-versa).

Comment: Suas permissões são "por tabela" (ex.: "usuário X pode acessar produtos") ou "por linha" (ex.: "usuário X pode acessar produto Y")? Um padrão comum é o [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), posso escrever uma resposta simplificada descrevendo ele. Mas antes preciso que essa dúvida seja esclarecida.

Comment: São por linha, Usuário X pode acessar produto Y e também preciso de permissões para "CRUD".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há duas opções pra você aqui: a **sem** integridade referencial e a **com**. A sem com certeza é mais simples, se você não se importar com a falta de chaves estrangeiras, mas se achar isso indispensável há uma alternativa com elas - no entanto você não vai escapar de criar uma tabela adicional para cada entidade do seu modelo.

Pra começar, crie os modelos básicos: `Usuario`, `Grupo`, `Permissao`, e as associações muitos-para-muitos `GrupoUsuario`, `PermissaoUsuario` e `PermissaoGrupo`. Essa separação vai facilitar muito sua vida. Explicitando: um usuário pertence a zero ou mais grupos e possui zero ou mais permissões. Além disso, o usuário **herda** as permissões do grupo (i.e. não precisa atribuir explicitamente uma permissão se um dos grupos onde ele está já tem essa permissão).

Você pode omitir `Grupo` se quiser simplificar seu modelo, às custas de um maior número de objetos do tipo `PermissaoUsuario` (pois cada novo usuário terá que receber explicitamente todas as permissões). Alternativamente, você pode omitir `PermissaoUsuario` caso não te interesse dar permissões individuais a um usuário, somente indiretamente através de um grupo. Fica a seu critério.

### Solução sem integridade referencial

O modelo `Permissao` deve ser mantido o mais simples possível: o `nome` da permissão, a `tabela` a qual ela se refere e a `linha` na tabela (possivelmente `NULL`), se aplicável. Exemplo:

```
Permissao
nome             tabela         linha
-------------------------------------
create           Produtos       NULL         <-  Usuário pode criar Produtos
read             Produtos       42           <-  Usuário pode ler o produto 42
read             Fornecedores   NULL         <-  Usuário pode ler Fornecedores
```

Verificar se um usuário tem permissão de acessar um registro é simples:

```
select 1
    from Usuario u
         join PermissaoUsuario pu on pu.id_usuario = u.id
         join Permissao        p  on pu.id_permissao = p.id
    where
         u.id = 10 and
         p.nome = 'read' and
         p.tabela = 'Produtos' and
         (p.linha = 42 or p.linha is null)
union
select 1
    from Usuario u
         join GrupoUsuario   gu on gu.id_usuario = u.id
         join PermissaoGrupo pg on pg.id_grupo = gu.id_grupo
         join Permissao      p  on pu.id_permissao = p.id
    where
         u.id = 10 and
         p.nome = 'read' and
         p.tabela = 'Produtos' and
         (p.linha = 42 or p.linha is null);
```

(Lembrando: se você omitiu `Grupo` ou `PermissaoUsuario` a parte de baixo ou de cima do `union`, respectivamente, não é necessária; e esse teste `is null` é só pro caso de um usuário ter permissão de acessar **todas** as linhas da tabela, se seu modelo não tem isso então você pode omitir essa parte)

### Solução com integridade referencial

Nesse caso seu modelo `Permissao` vai conter só o `nome` (i.e. não vai ter `tabela` nem `linha`), mas uma série de outros modelos vão ser criados para representar a permissão de acessar uma linha específica de um modelo específico. Por exemplo:

```
create table PermissaoProduto(
    id_permissao integer not null,
    id_produto   integer not null,
    primary key (id_permissao),
    foreign key (id_permissao) references Permissao(id),
    foreign key (id_produto)   references Produtos(id)
);
```

O resto fica igual. Assim, toda linha de `PermissaoProduto` estará **herdando** de uma linha de `Permissao` - pois ambas tem a mesma chave primária. A integridade referencial a `Usuario` fica por conta de `Permissao`,  a integridade referencial a `Produtos` fica por conta de `PermissaoProduto`. A verificação da permissão é igualmente simples, só tem um `join` a mais:

```
select 1
    from Usuario u
         join PermissaoUsuario pu on pu.id_usuario = u.id
         join Permissao        p  on pu.id_permissao = p.id
         join PermissaoProduto pp on p.id = pp.id_permissao
    where
         u.id = 10 and
         p.nome = 'read' and
         pp.id_produto = 42
union
select 1
    from Usuario u
         join GrupoUsuario   gu on gu.id_usuario = u.id
         join PermissaoGrupo pg on pg.id_grupo = gu.id_grupo
         join Permissao      p  on pu.id_permissao = p.id
         join PermissaoProduto pp on p.id = pp.id_permissao
    where
         u.id = 10 and
         p.nome = 'read' and
         pp.id_produto = 42;
```

Embora pareça complicado à primeira vista, manter uma tabela de permissões diferentes para cada modelo, a integração entre cada tipo de permissão e o usuário é a mesma - pois se dá através da tabela `Permissao`. Pessoalmente, eu usaria a solução **sem** integridade referencial, mas fica a critério de cada um.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @mgibsonbr de acordo com a sua analise chegue a conclusão que a  "Solução com integridade referencial" funcionará melhor pra mim. Obrigado por compartilhar o conhecimento.

Comment: O campo `linha` na tabela `Permissao` referencia um determinado registro de uma tabela?

Comment: @gato Sim, mas **sem** integridade referencial (i.e. ele referencia implicitamente, mas não é uma chave estrangeira). É de responsabilidade do programador garantir que o registro na tabela referenciada exista, pois se digamos não existir nenhum produto com id `42` - ou se o produto `42` for removido - o SGBD aceitará isso numa boa, sem nenhum erro.