# Criar níveis de acesso ao sistema

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Galera, esta pergunta parte do zero mesmo. Quero saber como faço para determinar regras de acesso ao sistema onde, existem 3 tipos de perfis: administrador geral, o administrador local e o mantenedor, onde existem regras diferentes para os perfis.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para cadastrar os usuários em devidos perfis e como dar permissões a eles em uma página!

Comment: Essa pergunta me parece ampla demais. E além do que, você precisa ter pelo menos uma base para podermos nos basear aqui (para uma eventual resposta). Do zero é difícil ajudar :D

Comment: Da uma olhada nas resposta desta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10945/27190).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando Rails, você pode criar essas regras no Backend usando [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Leia a documentação para instalação e configuração. Todas as regras de acesso são realizadas no arquivo `ability.rb`, pro seu caso sua configuração ficaria algo assim:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(usuario)
    usuario ||= Usuario.new 

    if usuario.administrador_geral?
      can :manage, :all
    end
    if usuario.administrador_local?
      can :manage, LocalModelOne
      can :manage, LocalModelTwo
    end

    if usuario.mantenedor?
      can :manage, RestrictModelOne
      can :manage, RestrictModelTwo
      can :read, VeryRestrictModelOne
    end


  end
end
```

Bom, coloquei umas regras falsas só pra você ter uma ideia da estrutura, mas você vai criar suas próprias regras.

Os métodos `administrador_geral?`, `administrador_local?` e `mantenedor?` são métodos de verificação que você vai criar em sua model `Usuario`, por exemplo

```
def mantenedor?
  usuario.tipo == MANTENEDOR_TIPO 
end
```

Só uma maneira de como pode ser feito, mas como sua pergunta está muito aberta, não tem como dar uma solução fechada, boa sorte.